# is ++ = +1 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Why when I use the following codes in JS it works properly ?:

```
let counter = 5;
while (counter < 10) {
  console.log(counter);
  counter ++;
}
```

But when I try the following codes it doesn't?

```
let counter = 5;
while (counter < 10) {
  console.log(counter);
  counter + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because on the second example, you are summing 1 to counter value, but it's not using this sum to nothing.

Let me exemplify:

```
let c = 0;

console.log(c + 1); // outputs 1

console.log(c); outputs 0, since in the last statement you didn't changed the original value, just used it.

console.log(c++); // will output c then increment c. So it prints the old value: 0

console log(c); will output 1 (result of previous increment)

console.log(++c); // will increment c and then output it new value: 2
```

Keep in mind that

```
c++;
```

Is the same that:

```
c = c + 1
```

Answer (score 4):

You're missing an assignment there.
`counter++` directly increases the counter itself by one.
`counter + 1` just returns the value of counter plus one.

Solutions might be:
`counter += 1;`
`counter = counter + 1;`

Answer (score 1):

The [increment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment) will increment a value and return a value that differs depending on whether it is used in a prefix or postfix position.

In postfix position it returns the original value:

```js
let x = 0
console.log(x++) // 0 (!!)
console.log(x) // 1
```

In prefix position it returns the new value:

```js
let x = 0
console.log(++x) // 1
console.log(x) // 1
```

You can type it out long hand if you want, using the [addition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Addition) and [assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Assignment) operators separately:

```js
let x = 0
console.log(x = x + 1) // 1
console.log(x) // 1
```

There is another operator too: the [addition assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment):

```js
let x = 0
console.log(x += 1) // 1
console.log(x) // 1
```